# How to import yaml when deploying Django app on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, import, importerror

I have a working Django App but when I try to deploy it on Heroku I get this error:

Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:
No module named yaml

```
ImportError at /crunchApp/contact
No module named yaml
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://desolate-citadel-5832.herokuapp.com/crunchApp/contact
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    No module named yaml
Exception Location: /app/crunchApp/Crunch.py in <module>, line 10
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['/app',
'/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg',
'/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
'/app',
 '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python27.zip',
'/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7',
'/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 22 Sep 2012 20:35:34 -0700
```

I am not sure what I need to update since the line that is crashing it simply says this:

```
import yaml
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

To expand on forvaidya's answer, *yaml* is missing from your requirements.txt file and that is why Heroku is not installing it when you commit your app. In your base directory, rerun the following command to make this work:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
git add .
git commit -m "fixed requirements.txt file"
```

...then push back to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

yaml module is either not present or not in path.

Comment: How can I make it present in the correct path? I believe I must have pip installed it before, will I need to re-install it in a different file? @jobless_at_bangalore